# mb_convert_encoding() и php 5.2.17

Tags: php, centos

Есть ли фукнция mb_convert_encoding() в php 5.2.17 или уже нет.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Проблема уже решена

Answer (score 1):

На http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php указано, что функция работает в php 5, но не указано, что она устарела. Значит, есть.
Чтобы включить в php mb-функции, раскомментируйте в файле php.ini строку 'extension=php_mbstring.dll'.

Comment: А как быть в случае с Linux ?

Comment: К сожалению, в случае Linux я подсказать ничего не могу. Знаю только, что это расширение нужно сначала установить.

Comment: Чем вам моя функция не угодила? ..А с линуксом тоже не сложно, надо найти конфиг пхп, и точно так-же там строчку раскоментировать, затем перезапустить веб-сервер.

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже не получилось воспользоваться этой функцией. Попробуйте iconv(). Например так:

```
<?php
  iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $_POST['val']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

выводит все доступные функции:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r( get_defined_functions() );
```